# How to get HTML form upload file path and move a file in any specific folder

Tags: php

I am trying to upload a text file using html form. after I submit, I don't get file path in php.

I tried  `$_FILES['file']['name'];` , `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];`, also tried to `echo $_POST['file'];` It shows only file name.

```
<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="getfile.php">    
    <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 position-relative form-group">
        <input name="file" type="file" class="">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

this is my PHP file

**getfile.php**

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $name_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $local_file = "uploaded/".$name_file;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$local_file);
}
?>
```

in this case **echo $_POST['file'];** shows only file name but the file is not moved to the folder

Comment: Try using  `$name_file =basename( $_FILES['file']['name']);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in `<form>` to upload a file.

Here is a working version of the code

```
<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $local_file = "uploaded/".$name_file;
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$local_file);
}
?>

<form class="form-inline" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0 position-relative form-group">
        <input name="file" type="file" class="">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```